# Hide columns in a DataGridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Let's say I have a table like so:

```
Friend
------
Id int not null
FriendName nvarchar(50) not null
Phone nvarchar(50) null
```

If I bind my `DataGridView` control in a Windows Forms application to an `ObjectQuery<Friend>`/`ObjectSet<Friend>`/`IList<Friend>` returned from an `ObjectContext` like so:

```
MyFriendsGridView.DataSource = _context.Friends.ToList();
```

All the columns that are in the *Friend* table appear in the grid. Suppose I want the *Id* column not to show up in the grid, how do I do that?

Do I simply hide the column in the grid's properties by setting the column's visibility to false? Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I think you got it.  You could also set the column width to zero.

Comment: You cannot set the column width to zero, as minimum width cannot be less than 2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.minimumwidth.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Setting column's visible property to false is the elegant solution as far as I know.